# ng-repeat not listing elements in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-repeat to list all elements in an array, and it isn't working.

This is the HTML code.

```
  <p ng-repeat="q in similarQuestions">
    Question: {{ q }}
  </p>
```

It seems to know how many elements there are in the  `similarQuestions` array, since it displays the same number of paragraphs, but it does not display any of the items in the array.

The `similarQuestions` array is generated with this JavaScript code:

```
  this.fetchSimilarQuestions = function() {
    var request = $http.get(`/api2/questions/${this.question.id}/get-similar-questions`);
    request.then(
      function success(response) {
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < response.data.similar_questions.length; index++) { 
          console.log(response.data.similar_questions[index]); 
          console.log(typeof response.data.similar_questions[index])
        } 
        $scope.similarQuestions = response.data.similar_questions;
        // this.apiErrors = {};
      },
      function error(response) {
        let data = response.data;
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        console.log('error finding duplicate questions:', api_data, data);
        this.apiErrors = data;
        this.hasAPIErrors = true;
        return
      }
    );
  }
```

What is going on?

Comment: What properties are on each object in similarQuestions? Let’s say id is a property could you instead do {{ q.id }} and see if that prints out? Can you also try {{ q | json }}

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky each element is a string.

Comment: similarQuestions is just an array of strings? Can you do {{ similarQuestions | json }} and update the question with the result?

Comment: What do your console logs output?

Comment: @tbone849 they output the questions (followed by their type, string), which is what I want to display with ng-repeat.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Will try that.